TV show episode featuring trees that develop a taste for death and become evil?
At least 15 years ago although it could be more, I saw what I believe was an episode of a TV mystery series. 
I don't remember anything about the beginning but what I do remember was that the conclusion was that evil trees....or wood was responsible for killing people. 
Essentially the wood used for carpentry in some houses came from woods where people used to be hung on trees and over time the trees developed a taste for death. There was something about the scent of the flowers at night effecting people...This is all worked out by the protagonist who is looking at a hand drawn picture in an old book/possibly torn page of a book since I think at some point in the episode he only has/or sees part of the picture, of a person hanging from a tree. Then later we see the previously missing or covered part of the picture is that the tree is somehow alive.
There is a scene were the protagonist runs into a house and rips off a newly laid piece of wood that looks like it has a moving eye on it. Because apparently the wood is alive and actively, somehow, trying to kill people.
It was in colour and I think British but that is not a definite. I remember the male as having dark brown hair but it was so long ago and has been floating in and out of my memory driving me insane for years!
Does anyone recognise the episode/series I am describing? 

Is it this one?

Yes it is! That you so much. Can't believe someone was asking about the same thing. Hero.
